# Docker run command no such file or directory

Tags: docker, cmake, dockerfile

I wrote a c++ application using `clion`, `cmake` to compile and run the project. The project worked perfectly while running it from terminal or clion.

I need to build a Docker Image to deploy the project and its my first time to use Docker. So I created the `DockerFile`

```
FROM gcc:5.4

# remove cmake

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get remove --purge -y \
    cmake \
 && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# build latest cmake

ARG cmake_sources="https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.0.tar.gz"
LABEL cmake-version=3.7.0

RUN cd /opt \
 && mkdir src \
 && curl -s $cmake_sources | tar -xz --strip-components=1 -C src \
 && cd src \
 && ./bootstrap \
 && make -j8 \
 && make install \
 && cd .. \
&& rm -rf src
RUN pwd
WORKDIR /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest
COPY . /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tree
RUN tree -x
RUN pwd
#RUN cmake .
#RUN make
RUN cmake -H. -Bbuild
RUN cmake --build build -- -j3
RUN tree -x
RUN stat /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out
RUN chmod +x /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out
CMD ["./home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"]
```

Then I build the image using

```
sudo docker build -t my_app .
```

And it do all steps correctly and it compile the project as shown the terminal.

Build log:

```
sudo docker build -t app_2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  371.2kB
Step 1/17 : FROM gcc:5.4
 ---> b87db7824271
Step 2/17 : RUN apt-get update  && apt-get remove --purge -y     cmake  && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y  && apt-get clean  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c23ca9008a7
Step 3/17 : ARG cmake_sources="https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.0.tar.gz"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> df7eca2dfdec
Step 4/17 : LABEL cmake-version=3.7.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 659f8e671fc0
Step 5/17 : RUN cd /opt  && mkdir src  && curl -s $cmake_sources | tar -xz --strip-components=1 -C src  && cd src  && ./bootstrap  && make -j8  && make install  && cd .. && rm -rf src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9926d53c476
Step 6/17 : RUN pwd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eed6b41de375
Step 7/17 : WORKDIR /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f1c50d7563ae
Step 8/17 : COPY . /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest
 ---> ab3cadd4f213
Step 9/17 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tree
 ---> Running in c633632b810f
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [94.4 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [646 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2434 B]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [23.1 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9064 kB]
Fetched 10.1 MB in 17s (578 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 88 not upgraded.
Need to get 45.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 102 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main tree amd64 1.7.0-3 [45.9 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 45.9 kB in 3s (15.2 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package tree.
(Reading database ... 21224 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tree_1.7.0-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tree (1.7.0-3) ...
Setting up tree (1.7.0-3) ...
Removing intermediate container c633632b810f
 ---> b8ee14ee0355
Step 10/17 : RUN tree -x
 ---> Running in 86327f018039
.
|-- AdvertisementServer.cpp
|-- AdvertisementServer.h
|-- ArrayQueue.h
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- Channel.cpp
|-- Channel.h
|-- ControlSession.cpp
|-- ControlSession.h
|-- Defines.h
|-- DeviceQoSManager.cpp
|-- DeviceQoSManager.h
|-- Dockerfile
|-- GlobalChannel.cpp
|-- GlobalChannel.h
|-- MaggotChannel.cpp
|-- MaggotChannel.h
|-- MaggotGarbageCollector.cpp
|-- MaggotGarbageCollector.h
|-- MaggotPacketQueue.cpp
|-- MaggotPacketQueue.h
|-- MaggotScheduler.cpp
|-- MaggotScheduler.h
|-- MaggotSender.cpp
|-- MaggotSender.h
|-- MaggotSession.cpp
|-- MaggotSession.h
|-- MaggotTcpPacket.cpp
|-- MaggotTcpPacket.h
|-- MaggotUdpChannel.cpp
|-- MaggotUdpChannel.h
|-- MainScheduler.cpp
|-- MainScheduler.h
|-- Makefile
|-- MptcpSession.cpp
|-- MptcpSession.h
|-- OutOfOrderQueue.cpp
|-- OutOfOrderQueue.h
|-- Packets.h
|-- Profiler.cpp
|-- Profiler.h
|-- ProxySocket.cpp
|-- ProxySocket.h
|-- RateCapped.h
|-- Receiver.cpp
|-- Receiver.h
|-- Reliable.h
|-- ReorderingQueue.cpp
|-- ReorderingQueue.h
|-- Retransmitter.cpp
|-- Retransmitter.h
|-- Running
|-- Safe_Queue.h
|-- Schedulable.h
|-- Session.cpp
|-- Session.h
|-- SessionKey.cpp
|-- SessionKey.h
|-- SharedLargeBufferPool.cpp
|-- SharedLargeBufferPool.h
|-- SharedPool.h
|-- TODO.txt
|-- TcpScheduler.cpp
|-- TcpScheduler.h
|-- TcpSession.cpp
|-- TcpSession.h
|-- TimerEventManager.cpp
|-- TimerEventManager.h
|-- UdpScheduler.cpp
|-- UdpScheduler.h
|-- UdpSession.cpp
|-- UdpSession.h
|-- Using
|-- Util.cpp
|-- Util.h
|-- VpnManager.cpp
|-- VpnManager.h
|-- b87db7824271
|-- cmake_install.cmake
|-- df7eca2dfdec
|-- e3255b76c200
|-- empty.c
|-- log.txt
|-- log.txt~
|-- rateCap
|-- second-
|-- sniffer.c
`-- socketOpt.c

0 directories, 87 files
Removing intermediate container 86327f018039
 ---> 906c6fc16d91
Step 11/17 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 1a98be53a294
/home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest
Removing intermediate container 1a98be53a294
 ---> 6929705f2df9
Step 12/17 : RUN cmake -H. -Bbuild
 ---> Running in b9ed7275783d
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build
Removing intermediate container b9ed7275783d
 ---> 39cf841de150
Step 13/17 : RUN cmake --build build -- -j3
 ---> Running in 2f0cc83e7dfa
Scanning dependencies of target MaggotProxy
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/Util.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/ProxySocket.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/VpnManager.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/UdpSession.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/UdpScheduler.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/TcpSession.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/TcpScheduler.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/SessionKey.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/Session.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/Receiver.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MptcpSession.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MainScheduler.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MaggotSession.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MaggotScheduler.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/GlobalChannel.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/Channel.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MaggotChannel.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/SharedLargeBufferPool.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MaggotTcpPacket.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/TimerEventManager.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/OutOfOrderQueue.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MaggotPacketQueue.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/Retransmitter.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MaggotUdpChannel.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/ControlSession.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/AdvertisementServer.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MaggotSender.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/ReorderingQueue.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MaggotProxy.dir/MaggotGarbageCollector.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable MaggotProxy
[100%] Built target MaggotProxy
Removing intermediate container 2f0cc83e7dfa
 ---> d1bb3504b194
Step 14/17 : RUN tree -x
 ---> Running in fec09156925b
.
|-- AdvertisementServer.cpp
|-- AdvertisementServer.h
|-- ArrayQueue.h
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- Channel.cpp
|-- Channel.h
|-- ControlSession.cpp
|-- ControlSession.h
|-- Defines.h
|-- DeviceQoSManager.cpp
|-- DeviceQoSManager.h
|-- Dockerfile
|-- GlobalChannel.cpp
|-- GlobalChannel.h
|-- MaggotChannel.cpp
|-- MaggotChannel.h
|-- MaggotGarbageCollector.cpp
|-- MaggotGarbageCollector.h
|-- MaggotPacketQueue.cpp
|-- MaggotPacketQueue.h
|-- MaggotScheduler.cpp
|-- MaggotScheduler.h
|-- MaggotSender.cpp
|-- MaggotSender.h
|-- MaggotSession.cpp
|-- MaggotSession.h
|-- MaggotTcpPacket.cpp
|-- MaggotTcpPacket.h
|-- MaggotUdpChannel.cpp
|-- MaggotUdpChannel.h
|-- MainScheduler.cpp
|-- MainScheduler.h
|-- Makefile
|-- MptcpSession.cpp
|-- MptcpSession.h
|-- OutOfOrderQueue.cpp
|-- OutOfOrderQueue.h
|-- Packets.h
|-- Profiler.cpp
|-- Profiler.h
|-- ProxySocket.cpp
|-- ProxySocket.h
|-- RateCapped.h
|-- Receiver.cpp
|-- Receiver.h
|-- Reliable.h
|-- ReorderingQueue.cpp
|-- ReorderingQueue.h
|-- Retransmitter.cpp
|-- Retransmitter.h
|-- Running
|-- Safe_Queue.h
|-- Schedulable.h
|-- Session.cpp
|-- Session.h
|-- SessionKey.cpp
|-- SessionKey.h
|-- SharedLargeBufferPool.cpp
|-- SharedLargeBufferPool.h
|-- SharedPool.h
|-- TODO.txt
|-- TcpScheduler.cpp
|-- TcpScheduler.h
|-- TcpSession.cpp
|-- TcpSession.h
|-- TimerEventManager.cpp
|-- TimerEventManager.h
|-- UdpScheduler.cpp
|-- UdpScheduler.h
|-- UdpSession.cpp
|-- UdpSession.h
|-- Using
|-- Util.cpp
|-- Util.h
|-- VpnManager.cpp
|-- VpnManager.h
|-- b87db7824271
|-- build
|   |-- CMakeCache.txt
|   |-- CMakeFiles
|   |   |-- 3.7.0
|   |   |   |-- CMakeCCompiler.cmake
|   |   |   |-- CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
|   |   |   |-- CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
|   |   |   |-- CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
|   |   |   |-- CMakeSystem.cmake
|   |   |   |-- CompilerIdC
|   |   |   |   |-- CMakeCCompilerId.c
|   |   |   |   `-- a.out
|   |   |   `-- CompilerIdCXX
|   |   |       |-- CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
|   |   |       `-- a.out
|   |   |-- CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
|   |   |-- CMakeOutput.log
|   |   |-- CMakeTmp
|   |   |-- MaggotProxy.dir
|   |   |   |-- AdvertisementServer.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- CXX.includecache
|   |   |   |-- Channel.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- ControlSession.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- DependInfo.cmake
|   |   |   |-- GlobalChannel.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MaggotChannel.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MaggotGarbageCollector.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MaggotPacketQueue.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MaggotScheduler.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MaggotSender.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MaggotSession.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MaggotTcpPacket.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MaggotUdpChannel.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MainScheduler.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- MptcpSession.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- OutOfOrderQueue.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- ProxySocket.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- Receiver.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- ReorderingQueue.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- Retransmitter.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- Session.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- SessionKey.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- SharedLargeBufferPool.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- TcpScheduler.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- TcpSession.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- TimerEventManager.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- UdpScheduler.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- UdpSession.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- Util.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- VpnManager.cpp.o
|   |   |   |-- build.make
|   |   |   |-- cmake_clean.cmake
|   |   |   |-- depend.internal
|   |   |   |-- depend.make
|   |   |   |-- flags.make
|   |   |   |-- link.txt
|   |   |   `-- progress.make
|   |   |-- Makefile.cmake
|   |   |-- Makefile2
|   |   |-- TargetDirectories.txt
|   |   |-- cmake.check_cache
|   |   |-- feature_tests.bin
|   |   |-- feature_tests.c
|   |   |-- feature_tests.cxx
|   |   `-- progress.marks
|   |-- MaggotProxy
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- cmake_install.cmake
|-- cmake_install.cmake
|-- df7eca2dfdec
|-- e3255b76c200
|-- empty.c
|-- log.txt
|-- log.txt~
|-- rateCap
|-- second-
|-- sniffer.c
`-- socketOpt.c

7 directories, 148 files
Removing intermediate container fec09156925b
 ---> 996a495e0747
Step 15/17 : RUN stat /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out
 ---> Running in 6fff7ee1a160
  File: '/home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out'
  Size: 7168        Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 2eh/46d Inode: 150866      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-04-21 14:23:44.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2018-04-21 14:23:44.000000000 +0000
Change: 2018-04-21 14:23:45.834455655 +0000
 Birth: -
Removing intermediate container 6fff7ee1a160
 ---> 157299bfb768
Step 16/17 : RUN chmod +x /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out
 ---> Running in 74c5fd286be5
Removing intermediate container 74c5fd286be5
 ---> bbd04a80e568
Step 17/17 : CMD ["./home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"]
 ---> Running in 2401dbf2ad3e
Removing intermediate container 2401dbf2ad3e
 ---> 00b888454e7e
Successfully built 00b888454e7e
Successfully tagged app_2:latest
```

When I run the image using

```
 sudo docker run -p 4000:80 my_app
```

The error message is:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out\": stat ./home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Comment: This really isn't a C++ question.  I'm not sure if it is even a Stack Overflow question.  Super Users might be the best place for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed your current directory here:

```
WORKDIR /home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest
```

And the command you run is based on a relative path instead of an absolute path:

```
CMD ["./home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"]
```

That results in looking for the executable:

```
/home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out
```

which doesn't exist. Remove the leading `.` from the path of your command to make it an absolute path.

```
CMD ["/home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a typo in the `CMD` stanza? Should it not be
`["./home/mohd/project/Test/AppName"]`? Without the extra **AppName**.

If that wasn't it, just run a stat after the `RUN make` step s to see if the file is actually there.

`RUN stat /home/mohd/project/<path>/<to>/<your>/<binary>`

If nothing comes up try to see what exactly is created by `make` and `cmake` in the current working directory.

`RUN tree -x`

And also make sure you set the executable bit on the program

`RUN chmod +x /home/mohd/project/<path>/<to>/<your>/<binary>`

Comment: When I run make using terminal it generate the executable file inside the project with the name project name, So test project will have test file inside it so I changed the command to `["./home/mohd/project/Test/Test"]`. And using state it shows that there is a file but tree -x didn't work not sure if used it correctly.

Comment: Looks like the docker image does not have `tree` inside, use a temporary step to install it before you run it `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tree`.

Comment: I updated the tree before and after make command also I updated the Dockerfile and I can see the complied file in `/home/mohd/project/MaggotProxyTest/build/MaggotProxy/` I am not sure why when I run the image it shows that file not found. Is it possible that docker remove the file from container after finishing the build command?

Comment: You answer helped my a lot to learn how to debug a small container.

Comment: You're welcome, i'm sorry i missed the point that @BMitch made and i thank him for answering, his point is accurate and in contrast with my points provided lots of information for investigating and fixing some or all the issues you faced, i'm glad we helped!